# Append a variable's value to a selector @if it exists (using variable-exists)

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to add in a class name to SCSS if it exists.

Using a base framework which outputs 2 CSS files.

- theme_1.css
- theme_2.css

Each CSS file is compiled from its respective SCSS file - which either contains a variable called `$body-container` or not.

`$body-container: .body-container;`

If the variable exists then it should be appended to the body tag.

This is the SCSS that I've tried so far

```
body @if(variable-exists(body-container)) { $body-container } {
  /* styles here */
}
```

I'm expecting the following:

For the SCSS file that contains the variable

```
body .body-container {
    /* styles here */
}
```

and without the variable declared

```
body {
    /* styles here */
}
```

But getting the following error `Error: Invalid CSS after "...body-container ": expected ":", was "} {"`

Comment: I don't think you can append a variable to a selector like that. However you can do something like [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dXGOdm) (*note that I am just a beginner in Sass/SCSS and there could be better ways to do this*).

Comment: Nice work around to the problem. Thanks! +1

Comment: I'll wait sometime to see if any better answer comes. If none, I'll post my workaround as an answer :)

Comment: I changed it slightly to: `$selector: "body " + $body-wrapper !global;` and set a variable `$body-wrapper: ".bodywrapper";` Only minor but allowed me to have a variable name different to the value. Might help others too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, I don't think it is possible to append a variable to a selector in that way (the one used in question). The error message indicates that it expects a `:` after the variable name which is implying that it is expecting a *value assignment* to the variable within the `@if` loop.

Having said that, it is still possible to achieve this using the below workaround. The idea is to see if the variable is defined and if yes, set another dummy variable (`$selector`) as the concatenation of `body` and the original variable's (`$body-container`) value. If not, then just set it as `body`.

Then we can use this dummy variable (`$selector`) through interpolation. So, if `$body-container` has been defined the selector would be `body .body-container`. Else, it would simply be `body`.

```css
$body-container: ".body-container";
@if variable-exists(body-container) {
  $selector: "body " + $body-container !global;
}

@else {
  $selector: "body" !global;
}

#{$selector} {
  color: red;
}
```